# Sonar in bamboo, checkstyle and jacoco local builds

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

New to Sonar. Am comfortable with checkstyle and jacoco.

What I am exploring is in a a gradle project, give developers ability to run style checks and code coverage reports locally, but then use bamboo to publish reports in sonar.

Is this a viable option ? I can see that jacoco plugin and sonar plugin can be in the same  build.gradle and so guessing that jacoco reports can be got from sonar. However am unsure how checkstyle integration works. From what I see, I can add a checkstyle plugin to sonar, but then I will have to define rules in SonarQube. I will like to keep checkstyle configuration locally so developers can run a local check before commiting code.

Bear with me if the questions are naive.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal: enable developers to run the same set of rules locally that are applied in a SonarQube scan.

The means: [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) offers a "connected mode" for IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Visual Studio. Assuming you're using the SonarQube Analyzers, they'll get on-the-fly checking as they code using the same rule set locally as is applied in an analysis. If the profile changes on the server, it can be manually re-synchronized in the IDE.

The hitch: to make this work seamlessly, you should look at replacing your Checkstyle rules with the ones offered by the SonarQube Analyzer for Java (i.e. the Java plugin). Almost all of the "valuable" rules from Checkstyle have been replaced in the Java plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I rather like to be IDE agnostic and instead want to be running a gradle plugin or the like to do a build time check (in-addition to of-course have an on-the-fly code checking IDE checkin. And another question that comes to my mind, is how do I keep the two in sync. - SonarLint settings in the IDE and SonarQube settings. One is maintained in a server and the other as part of your IDE setting.